# How to prove Maxwell's mutual inductance between two parallel circular loops integral?

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals

Where can I possibly find a source to demonstrate the following integral, or how should I even begin to demonstrate it (I am stuck)?

$$\oint \frac{\cos(\theta) \, d\theta}{\sqrt{a-b\cos(\theta)}}=\frac{4\sqrt{a+b}}{b} \left[\left(1-\frac{\beta^2}{2}\right)K(\beta)-E(\beta)\right]$$

where: 
$$\beta=\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a+b}}$$

Comment: Replace $\cos\left(\, \theta\, \right)$ in the $\sqrt{\mbox{}}$ by $1 - 2\sin^{2}\left(\, \theta \over 2\, \right)$ and looks at tables.

Comment: 1) What are the limits of integration on $\theta$? My guess would be $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. 2) What definitions of the complete elliptic integrals are you using? There are unfortunately two different conventions for their arguments. (Namely, whether one writes it as $K(k)$ or as $K(m)$ with $m=k^2$.)